# MVVM - Model data available for multiple viewModels

Tags: c#, xml, mvvm

currently I am learning MVVM and now I have a newbie question.

***Let's assume my application is structured as follows***

**viewModel**

- ViewModelA
- ViewModelB
- ViewModelC

**Model**

- ModelX

The model should save all informations from a "config.xml" file which read at the start of the application.

**Programm step chain**

1. Application starts
2. **viewModelA** would execute the function called "readXML"
3. Some informations of config.xml should be displayed in view1 and some other in view2 and so on. Thats the reason for my following question...

How can I provide now the read XML data for **all** viewModels?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are these view models widely different in scope and function? Part of MVVM is being reusing your viewmodel between views. The viewmodel shouldn't care what view is attached to it at all.

Comment: You could move the XML reading into a different class (you could name it XmlReader - very intuitive), populate a model instance with the results of XML reading and provide the same model instance to all 3 VM instances...

Comment: @JonBangsberg: Not really, the viewModels are only for data binding. For example some ObservableCollections to create dynamic textbooxes in my views. But I thought each view should have its own ViewModel? According to you, I could make view1,2,3 known with viewModelA and so bind the data?

Comment: @lidgy: is your suggestion MVVM compliant? you want me to pass the class XMLreader as parameter to the viewmodels isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The `structure` of `mvvm` should be as follows. You can use a `singleton` class to use a shared resource

***Model***

1. ModelA
2. ModelB
3. ModelC

***View***

1. ViewA
2. ViewB
3. ViewC

***ViewModel***

1. ViewModelA
2. ViewModelB
3. ViewModelC

Now define the `ModelX` class as a `singleton` class. You can use the following class in all `viewmodels`.

```
public class XMLData
{
   private XMLData()
   {
   }
   private static XMLData instance = null;
   public static XMLData Instance
   {
      get
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
             instance = new XMLData();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
   
   public static void ReadXMl()
   {
       //to do
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try next week. Will give feedback afterwards